# Compile a regex that will automatically escape or ignore special characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the results of one regex to build another regex, more or less like this:

```
regex = '(?P<prev>.+?)(?P<hook>\%\%.+?\%\%)(?P<next>.+?$)'
match = re.search(regex, content, re.S)

comparisonRegex = match.group('prev') + 
    '(?P<desiredContent>desireable)' + match.group('next')
match = re.search(comparisonRegex, otherContent, re.S)
```

this approach works fine, but sometimes it will throw this error:

```
  File "/path/to/my/script/refactor_static.py", line 92, in dynamicContent
    match = re.search(comparisonRegex, crawlFileContent, re.S)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

I'm fairly confident this is because the content I'm searching through and using as a new regex has invalid characters or sequences in it, but I'm not sure how to approach this. Is there an argument I can pass that will essentially tell it to compile all the letters as literals and not as special characters? So far I haven't been able to find anything in the [python regex guide](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Your example in this question is a poor example. With `stuff` and `thing` in this case being fixed string, the problem with special character can never occur.

Comment: I've edited it to make it more clear for future people. It was merely a placeholder.

Comment: I'm aware it's placeholder, but other people may not. You need to demonstrate a reproducible problem to make it a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape)

```
regex = '(?P<prev>.?+)(\%\%.+?\%\%)(?P<next>.+?$)'
match = re.search(regex, content, re.S)

comparisonRegex = re.escape(match.group('prev')) + 
    '(?P<desiredContent>desireable)' + re.escape(match.group('next'))
match = re.search(comparisonRegex, otherContent, re.S)
```